# Треугольник с помощью цикла do-while

Tags: java, циклы

Нужно решить задачу, нарисовать треугольник из долларов, есть условия:

1. Цикл только do while.
2. Не более двух циклов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получается пока только нижняя часть рисунка, и через `while`:

```java
int n = 3; 
int i = n, j = 1; 
while (i >= 1) { 
    while (j <= i) { 
        System.out.print(" " + "#"); 
        j++; 
    } 
    System.out.println(""); 
    j = 1; 
    i--; 
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Надо вывести в консоль этот тругольник,используя 2 цикла do while. У меня получается пока только нижняя часть рисунка,и через while. int n = 3;
        int i = n, j = 1;
        while (i >= 1)
        {
            while (j <= i)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + "#");
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println("");
            j = 1;
            i--;
 }}

Comment: Там решеткой рисунок,но это не принципиально

Comment: Символы надо выводить не по одному в цикле, а сразу делать строку нужной длины и выводить целиком. Верхняя часть делается так же, как нижняя, только наоборот.

Comment: Можете в виде кода написать,если не затруднит

Answer (score 0):

Если используется отдельный цикл для поэлементного вывода каждой строки, как в представленном решении, то придётся завести ещё несколько переменных:

- общее количество строк будет вычисляться по формуле `m = 2 * n - 1`
- текущая "ширина" строки, которая может как увеличиваться, так и уменьшаться
- соответственно, "приращение ширины", которое может принимать значения `1`, `-1`
  Получится что-то вроде:

```java
int 
    n = 3,         // "высота" треугольника (максимальная ширина)
    m = 2 * n - 1, // общее количество строк
    i = 1,         // счётчик строк (от 1) 
    d = 1,         // "приращение"
    w = 1;         // ширина строки
do {
    int j = 0;     // счётчик элементов текущей строки

    do {
        System.out.print("$");
    } while (++j < w);
    System.out.println();

    // достигли максимальной ширины, начинаем уменьшать текущую ширину
    if (i == n) d = -1;
    w += d;
} while (++i <= m);
```

---

Если можно использовать метод для генерации строк [`String::repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)), добавленный в Java 11, то можно будет обойтись *технически* одним циклом, определив отдельный метод:

```java
public static void printTriangleOneLoop(int n, String str) {
    int i = 0, d = 1, w = 1, m = 2 * n - 1;
    do {
        System.out.println(str.repeat(w));  // вывод строки с текущей шириной
        if (++i == n) d = -1;               // достигли максимума
        w += d;
    } while (i < m);
}
```

Или же можно использовать последовательно два цикла без дополнительных переменных и логики, в первом ширина будет увеличиваться, во втором, соответственно, уменьшаться:

```java
public static void printTriangleTwoLoops(int n, String str) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println(str.repeat(++i));
    } while (i < n);
    do {
        System.out.println(str.repeat(--i));
    } while (i > 1);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ПавелМиронов, если ответ оказался полезным, можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку.