# Поиск одинаковых цифр в сотнях

Tags: java

```java
int a = 123;
int b = 223;
int ones1, tens1, hundreds1;
int ones2, tens2, hundreds2;
    
ones1 = a % 10;
tens1 = (a / 10) % 10;
hundreds1 = (a / 100) % 10;
    
ones2 = b % 10;
tens2 = (b / 10) % 10;
hundreds2 = (b / 100) % 10;
System.out.println("Исходные числа: " + a + " и " + b);
    
if (ones1 == ones2) {
    System.out.println("Цифры совпадают в разряде " + "3" +
    " , совпавшие цифры: " + ones1 + " и " + ones2);
}
if (tens1 == tens2) {
    System.out.println("Цифры совпадают в разряде " + "2" +
    " , совпавшие цифры: " + tens1 + " и " + tens2);
}
if (hundreds1 == hundreds2) {
    System.out.println("Цифры совпадают в разряде " + "1" +
    " , совпавшие цифры: " + hundreds1 + " и " + hundreds2);
} else {
    System.out.println("Нет совпадающих цифр");
}
```

Такая задача. Даны 2 трехзначных числа, нужно найти в них одинаковые цифры, если они есть, в определенных разрядах (сотни, десятки, единицы).

Использовать только `if`, циклы не изучали пока.  Если одинаковых цифр нет, то проверка не должна выполняться.

Я написал так, но в моем коде есть недостатки, как выяснилось на проверке.

Помимо выявления одинаковых цифр, выводится сообщение "нет совпадающих цифр", а так же выполняется проверка по разрядам, даже если числа разные. Как исправить, не подскажете?

Comment: Павел, скажите, почему вы решили, что добавить информацию о вопросе в комментарии - это лУчше, чем добавить эту информацию в сам вопрос?

Comment: Не дает отправить,пишет,что код не отформатирвоан

Comment: А вы не пробовали его....эммм.... отформатировать? Это же не спроста написано

Comment: И исправьте ошибки в правописании. Глаза режет от их количества.

Comment: Пробовал,загонял в форматировщик,но безуспешно

Comment: Что такое "безуспешно"? Ну ручками сделайте. Или вы не умеете? А в IDE вы как пишете?

Comment: Я новичок,не обесудьте

Comment: Ну вот учитесь... Сформируйте нормальный форматированный код и вставьте в вопрос... На текущий момент с такой подачей вам никто не будет помогать

Comment: Ок,но я не совсем понимаю правила форматирования.

Comment: Правила форматирования в языке Java или правила форматирования на текущем ресурсе? Если в языке - придётся читать где-либо и вникать, а если на ресурсе - то достаточно вставить свой нормальный код и в редакторе выделить его и нажать кнопку https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EnG8.png   либо форматировать его по правилам языка программирования

Comment: @ПавелМиронов, вы не  новичок, это ваш **четвёртый** вопрос.  Ваш [первый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1566828/) был о рисовании треугольника в цикле `do-while`, так что циклы вы изучали.

Comment: Не изучал,на момент где делал это домашнее задание.Циклы в более поздних ДЗ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Если одинаковых цифр нет, то проверка не должна выполняться.*

Это абсурдное утверждение, так как невозможно установить наличие одинаковых цифр без проверки.

Скорее всего, следовало сначала сравнить оба числа *без разбиения на разряды*, и выдать соответствующее сообщение типа "Числа равны, все разряды у них попарно одинаковы" в случае равенства входных чисел `a` и `b`.

Иначе выполняете разбиение на разряды, и сначала проверяете условие, что **все разряды разные**, и только потом смотрите попарно:

```java
if (a == b) {
    System.out.println("Числа равны, все разряды одинаковы");
} else {
    // разбиение чисел на разряды
    int ones1 = a % 10, tens1 = a / 10 % 10, hunds1 = a / 100 % 10; 
    int ones2 = b % 10, tens2 = b / 10 % 10, hunds2 = b / 100 % 10; 

    if (ones1 != ones2 && tens1 != tens2 && hunds1 != hunds2) {
        System.out.println("Нет совпадающих цифр, все разряды разные");
    } else {
        // попарное сравнение соответствующих разрядов
        if (ones1 == ones2) System.out.println("Единицы равны");
        if (tens1 == tens2) System.out.println("Десятки равны");
        if (hunds1 == hunds2) System.out.println("Сотни равны");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ахаха, и правда абсурдное.Сейчас сам читаю и смешно,правильнее сказать,"если цифры в разрядах разные,то уже не должна выполняться поразрядная проверка"Дословно цитирую ментора.

Answer (score 0):

`else` в этом коде относится к `if (hundreds1 == hundreds2)`. Поэтому если в разряде сотен стоят разные цифры, то выводится "Нет совпадающих цифр" вне зависимости от других результатов.